# SSL certificates for local web applications

Tags: dns, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, domain-name

My understanding is that there are three ways you could go about setting up a intranet web server (local network only) for HTTPS.

1. Self signed SSL certificate. Cons: Browsers typically don't likes these. Lots of ugly warnings at the very least.
2. Create your own SSL Certificate Authority. Cons: You have to manually install the CA on *every* single device that will be accessing the site (assuming it is even possible on every platform you might encounter.)
3. Purchase a real (external) domain name and get a SSL cert that covers a subdomain which will only exist in your internal DNS.

Options 1 & 2 are IMO a nonstarter for the fact that the user experience is absolutely horrible at best. Option 3 is also very non-ideal for a few reasons. For one, it requires you to spend money and keep a domain renewed. Lets say hypothetically that this web app was something you envisioned everyone and their mother wanting to use (by use I mean run their own local version on their private network). That would require everyone who wants to run this app to register a domain. That's a fairly huge requirement and barrier for entry.

**My real question is this**: would it make sense for IANA to reserve a TLD *specifically* for private networks, and then for web browsers to accept self-signed SSL certificates from domains bearing this TLD *if and only if* that domain resolves to a private IP address?

Comment: There is virtually no difference between the first and second option since in both cases the user of the client is manually trusting and installing your certificate. The process of installing a SSL certificate that’s been created for a local intranet domain isn’t that difficult. Something that anyone setting what you describe should be willing to do.  There are also free SSL certificates that are trusted by all browsers on all operating systems (Let’s Encrypt)

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, so just write up an manual with chapters for every operating system on how to obtain the .PEM file or whatever and give the user instructions on how to install the CA. I'm sure that wont confuse Grandma, I mean she's so good at these kinds of things.

Comment: Sorry, this is a non-starter. the whole reason that browsers no longer trust self-signed certs is that their origins cannot be trusted, and your scenario will lead to exploits. Making it trivial for Grandma to run a webserver is never going to be a priority for web governance and to be honest the barriers to entry are intentional. for instance crime is more common on lower cost TLDs. besides, your scheme relies on the LAN having DNS infrastructure, so the complexity is already built in. The value of HTTPS in this case is pretty minimal anyway. just use HTTP.

Comment: @FrankThomas and what exactly is the harm if this only works with a specifically designated local TLD? In order to exploit it you would A) need to set up a server on someone's LAN and B) be limited to only providing a local domain. It's not like you could impersonate Google or JPMorgan under what I proposed.

Comment: first thought is phishing. for instance a DNSChanger malware repoints the IP address of the local server to a remote server under the attackers control, which then steals your login credentials. HTTPS Certificate infrastructure is designed to ensure that you know when the server you intended to connect to is not the one you are actually connected to, and there is no way to do that when the cert is for an unregistered domain, and there is no way to make sure that the endpoints identified by any given host for your local TLD are in fact local.

Comment: @FrankThomas the browser would see the local-specific-TLD (lets say .lan) and it would be expecting it to resolve to a local IP address. If it somehow resolves to a public IP then the browser would not accept the self signed cert. If the browser got a domain name that did not use the .lan TLD then it would not accept the self signed cert regardless of how it resolved. It would be a specific expectation for when a mysite.lan domain resolves to a local IP address, and *only* that specific case. So I still don't see your concern, unless you are worried about something like google.lan being used?

Comment: feel free to try to convince the international web governance organizations and browser manufacturers. Pitching to us doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @FrankThomas No, but if more knowledgeable people can sanity check the idea then maybe I can be more reassured that there is potentially some merit to the thought.

Comment: This is a horribly short-sighted idea that would open the doors to tons of intranet phishing and “man in the middle” attacks.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm sorry, but I don't see how. Could you maybe explain a basic example of an attack that would be possible?

Comment: Malware infects a network, sets up a phishing site on a local machine, adjusts the `/etc/hosts` file to redirect things like a bank domain to something like `bank.lan`. There you go! Certificate will say it is a valid site, someone enters their credentials and then… Snatch! In all honesty this idea, if it were viable, would have been done. If you think this is an oversight, contact the IANA to see if you can influence them to do such a thing. You also state, “ It's not like you could impersonate Google or JPMorgan under what I proposed.” Yes! You could! Web servers are trivial to set up!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Do you mean the modified hosts file world resolve bank.com to the ip address of a malware server running locally? If so then this will not work by design. bank.com does not use the magic TLD (as it were), so the browser will absolutely not accept the self signed cert.

Comment: @Chris_F I’m sorry, but your rationale here shows your ignorance as to how this stuff works. There are simply two types of certs: Self-signed or not. Yeah, you can create your own CA but that is — as pointed out perviously by Frank Thomas — are effectively the same thing. It seems to me you believe this is a great idea. This site is not about extended theoretical discussions like what you are engaging in here in the comments. This site is about a real question that has a real solution. Please contact [the IANA directly](https://www.iana.org/contact) and float your idea with them.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 You claim I am ignorant which i do not deny and yet you do not provide compelling evidence that I am actually wrong about anything, leaving me with doubt about whether or not you have actually comprehended my question correctly.

Comment: @Chris_F This question is one close vote away from being closed. And again, this site is not about extended theoretical discussions like what you are engaging in here in the comments. I completely understand your “question” but I put the word question in quotes because your whole behavior here in the comments shows you have already decided this is a good idea and somehow should be implemented and you are effectively daring others to prove you wrong. If you ask a “question” you need to be ready for all answers and comments; including the ones you disagree with.

Comment: PS: “Lets say hypothetically that this web app was something you envisioned everyone and their mother wanting to use (by use I mean run their own local version). That would require everyone who wants to run this app to register a domain.” Somehow you are creating problem that simply does not exist at all since millions of apps out there from millions of developers can run locally on people’s own machines without doing something like hack TLD structure to force a certificate to work. I’ve been developing for years and have never run into a production scenario as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Just because a web server is on a local network does not mean its the one you are intending to visit and has not been compromised.

Further what defines a local network? What is to stop someone abusing a "special local tld"? How do you define local and handle its exceptions? How can you be sure that because something is on the LAN its not been compromised or MITM'd?

BTW, there is already a `.local` special domain name reserved for local networking.

Comment: Point of clarification: by "local" IP address I meant to say *private* IP address. That's not a subjective distinction.

Comment: @Chris_F What makes you think one cannot spoof or proxy an IP address for one thing to pretend it is another thing? Or that somehow a private IP address can’t be redirected to a malicious site? You are in over your head in your desire to oversimplify something just because you see a LAN as a safe space.

Comment: @ChrisF its absolutely a subjective distinction.   Taken to a bit of anextreme its entirely practical to subnet 192.168.0.0/24 further, and its COMMON to connect to networks with RFC1918 (ie private IP space) between multiple networks.

Comment: "Just because a web server is on a local network does not mean its the one you are intending to visit and has not been compromised." The point is you would only have to worry about a local server on your private network possibly interfering with another local server on your private network. Explain how this somehow opens the door to you compromising something like google.com for a user.

Comment: The .local domain is used by Apple for other purposes. It's been tainted and is no longer feely available for this exclusive use.

Comment: Where do I start?  A local server on a "private network" could be a local server on a private network belonging to someone else (common if you connect with related businesses without going across the wider Internet, or using a VPN.  A domain name is not fundamentally associated with an IP address, and there is no easy and secure way to implement this (just for a start different levels of the OSI model, problems with remote nameservers and DOH).   Even assuming a private network, if it has WIFI a hacker can breach it and plant a device and MITM/redirect stuff...

Comment: @Chris_F What is your real question here? To push this back to you, can you effectively explain why you are seemingly the only developer in the world who somehow has this supposedly “problem?” Why are you engaging in a software engineering structure that somehow requires that you hack the basic way CA and TLD works?

Comment: Malware can compromise another device which can then act as a MITM - the whole idea of "inflection points"),

Comment: Thank you. Your comment about subnetting a private address space was the hole in my logic that I needed to see. Maybe I shouldn't open questions when I'm sleep deprived.